# How to allow a tkinter window to be opened multiple times

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a makeshift sign in system with python. Currently if you enter the correct password it brings up a new admin window. If you enter the wrong one it brings up a new window that says wrong password. If you exit out of one of those windows and then try to enter a password again it breaks. `tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed` Is there a way to prevent this so if someone enters the wrong password they don't need to restart the app?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

#define root window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
root.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)

#define admin window
admin = tkinter.Tk()
admin.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
admin.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)
admin.withdraw()

#define wrong window
wrong = tkinter.Tk()
wrong.minsize(width=200, height = 100)
wrong.maxsize(width=200, height = 100)
wrong.withdraw()
Label(wrong, text="Sorry that password is incorrect!", font=("Arial", 24), anchor=W, wraplength=180, fg="red").pack()

#Admin sign in Label
areAdmin = Label(root, text="Administrator sign in", font=("Arial", 18))
areAdmin.pack()

#password label and password
passwordLabel = Label(root, text="Password: ", font=("Arial", 12))
passwordLabel.place(x=300, y=30)

#password entry
adminPasswordEntry = Entry(root)
adminPasswordEntry.place(x=385, y=32.5)

#function for button
def getEnteredPassword():
    enteredPassword = adminPasswordEntry.get()
    if enteredPassword == password:
        admin.deiconify()
    else:
        wrong.deiconify()

#enter button for password
passwordEnterButton = Button(root, text="Enter", width=20, command=getEnteredPassword)
passwordEnterButton.place(x=335, y=60)


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know `tkinter` much but I could fix your code, I hope it's a proper fix.

1. Create `Toplevel` windows not `Tk`. those are dialog windows, as opposed to `Tk` window which must be unique. Same look & feel, same methods
2. Create windows when needed, and each time. Else, closing them using the close gadget destroys them.

Fixed code, enter wrong or good password as many times you want without crash:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

password="good"

#define root window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
root.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)



#Admin sign in Label
areAdmin = Label(root, text="Administrator sign in", font=("Arial", 18))
areAdmin.pack()

#password label and password
passwordLabel = Label(root, text="Password: ", font=("Arial", 12))
passwordLabel.place(x=300, y=30)

#password entry
adminPasswordEntry = Entry(root)
adminPasswordEntry.place(x=385, y=32.5)

#function for button
def getEnteredPassword():
    enteredPassword = adminPasswordEntry.get()
    if enteredPassword == password:
        admin = tkinter.Toplevel()
        admin.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
        admin.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)
        #admin.withdraw()
    else:
        wrong = tkinter.Toplevel()
        wrong.minsize(width=200, height = 100)
        wrong.maxsize(width=200, height = 100)
        Label(wrong, text="Sorry that password is incorrect!", font=("Arial", 24), anchor=W, wraplength=180, fg="red").pack()


#enter button for password
passwordEnterButton = Button(root, text="Enter", width=20, command=getEnteredPassword)
passwordEnterButton.place(x=335, y=60)


mainloop()
```

Comment: it's funny I started out coding admin into the if statement and then decided not too, I guess I should have, thanks for the answer. What is the wrong=None and admin=None for?